# Jooq to validate each row of a CSV with a table in my schema

Tags: java, sql, csv, jooq

I would like to load a CSV into multiple tables which are interrelated. First thing I want to know how can I load the fields of a CSV into multiple tables at once. Also, before inserting I have to validate the fields with the columns in the tables, so is there any way to read the CSV file row by row? Thanks :)

Indexes are nothing but the positions of the values in CSV :)if i have a line like this "Smith jodan,LA,30,+01233444 " .Here smith jodan has to go in one table which holds name of a person and LA is his address that has to go into another table .

Comment: There's no such feature in jOOQ right now. But perhaps there should be. Based on what do you decide in what table to put a specific row? Can you add some more details to your question?

Comment: Ok here is my problem ,Lets suppose i have a csv with 5 fields with indexes 0 to 4 . the values in 0 , 1 should go into first table and 2,3, 4 to another table and also before inserting i would like to verify if the table already has this values because i have unique constraints on my tables.

Comment: Right now am reading the file line by line and using jooq to verify , persist the values into tables without using loadCsv.

Comment: Vinay, you can edit the question here on Stack Overflow. It will be easier to answer, this way. :) While you edit: Based on what do you discriminate these indexes? On hard-coded index numbers? Or on content?

Answer (score 0):

This currently cannot be done with jOOQ 3.7 out of the box. You'll have to pre-process your CSV file and dispatch the different rows to different individual loaders, one for each target table.

You can use the array importing API for this, for convenience:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-arrays